# InternalServerError when making PullSubscription with SubscribeToAllFolders

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use the `PullSubscription` with the `SubscrubeToAllFolders` attribute as documented on the [Microsoft Office Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563455(v=exchg.150).aspx):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <s:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <m:Subscribe>
            <m:PullSubscriptionRequest SubscribeToAllFolders="">
                <t:FolderIds />
                <t:EventTypes>
                    <t:EventType>CopiedEvent</t:EventType>
                    <t:EventType>CreatedEvent</t:EventType>
                    <t:EventType>DeletedEvent</t:EventType>
                    <t:EventType>ModifiedEvent</t:EventType>
                    <t:EventType>MovedEvent</t:EventType>
                    <t:EventType>NewMailEvent</t:EventType>
                    <t:EventType>FreeBusyChangedEvent</t:EventType>
                </t:EventTypes>
                <t:Watermark />
                <t:Timeout>1</t:Timeout>
            </m:PullSubscriptionRequest>
        </m:Subscribe>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

However this will always return an `ErrorInternalServerError` with text `An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.` and no `faultactor`. I've tried this with and without the superfluous `<t:FolderIds />` and `<t:Watermark/>` tags. With different timeouts and different contents of `<t:EventTypes>`.

But when I remove the `SubscribeToAllFolders=""` and add in the folders manually like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <s:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <m:Subscribe>
            <m:PullSubscriptionRequest>
                <t:FolderIds>
                    <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox" />
                </t:FolderIds>
                <t:EventTypes>
                    <t:EventType>CopiedEvent</t:EventType>
                    <t:EventType>CreatedEvent</t:EventType>
                    <t:EventType>DeletedEvent</t:EventType>
                    <t:EventType>ModifiedEvent</t:EventType>
                    <t:EventType>MovedEvent</t:EventType>
                    <t:EventType>NewMailEvent</t:EventType>
                    <t:EventType>FreeBusyChangedEvent</t:EventType>
                </t:EventTypes>
                <t:Watermark />
                <t:Timeout>10</t:Timeout>
            </m:PullSubscriptionRequest>
        </m:Subscribe>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I get the expected response.

Anyone had any problems with `SubscribeToAllFolders` before? Is there a way to get it working? I'm relatively new to EWS and SOAP so am I doing anything definitively stupid up my end? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request isn't formatted correctly eg it should look like

```html
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:Subscribe>
        <m:PullSubscriptionRequest SubscribeToAllFolders="true">
          <t:EventTypes>
            <t:EventType>CopiedEvent</t:EventType>
            <t:EventType>CreatedEvent</t:EventType>
            <t:EventType>DeletedEvent</t:EventType>
            <t:EventType>ModifiedEvent</t:EventType>
            <t:EventType>MovedEvent</t:EventType>
            <t:EventType>NewMailEvent</t:EventType>
          </t:EventTypes>
          <t:Timeout>5</t:Timeout>
        </m:PullSubscriptionRequest>
      </m:Subscribe>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

I'd suggest you look at using the EWSEditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ to do some testing it will both let you test the operation and give you the SOAP used for each request and response.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that I didn't have `"true"` set in `SubscribeToAllFolders`. I don't believe that was particularly clear in the documentation. Once I changed that, everything worked, no problems with formatting or anything.